# Shouldnt testng suite xml execute all the methods given under class name by default

Tags: testng

Tests wont execute until i dont give method names in testng.xml under class tag. Shouldnt testng suite xml execute all the methods given under class name by default if we dont specify method names.
Could you please guide me what i am missing here.

```
Below is my testng.xml


<suite name="SDP_Suite" verbose="2">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.xxx.TestValidationErrorListener" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter"/>  
</listeners>
    <test name="SDP_Tests"> 
    <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="Regression"/> 
      <exclude name="config"/>
    </run>
  </groups> 
            <classes>
                <class name="com.xxx.ResponsiveUI.tests.N1Tests"/>

                <class name="com.xxx.ResponsiveUI.tests.Q1Tests"/>

            </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TestNG will execute all tests in test class in case suite-test-classes-class. In your xml you are excluding "config" group, may be some of tests depends on cofiguration methods marked with this group and if this configuration is skipped test methods will be skipped too.

Answer (score 0):

Not simply so, if you want to execute all methods in the class as tests, you have to mark them all as `@Test` or make them all public and mark by `@Test` the class itself.

[TestNG doc:](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#class-level)

The effect of a class level @Test annotation is to make all the public methods of this class to become test methods even if they are not annotated. You can still repeat the @Test annotation on a method if you want to add certain attributes.

And after that, you have to launch the class by a suite or by IDE or Maven/Gradle will find and test it if you haven't any suite.